# script to run vba code in specifik workbook at certain time

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I know nothing about scripts and batch files, but i have maneged to read some about it to be able to start and try to write a code that i then want to put in my windows task schedule.

What i want to do is, Open an specifik excel workbook, run a macro named HamtaData and then save workbook and close.

what i have today is, Script (Filename STARTexcel)

```
dim args, objExcel

set args = wscript.arguments
set objExcel = CreateObject ("Excel.Application")

start Excel.exe "\\global.com\home\Se\58\dx\Desktop\Test\Deliveries.xlsm" 'This is the workbook i want to open.
objExcel.run "HamtaData" ' this is the macro i want to run.

objExcel.activeworkbook.Save
objExcel.activeworkbook.Close(0)
objExcel.Quit
```

My batch file is,

```
 cscript STARTexcel.vbs "\\global.com\home\Se\58\dx\Desktop\Test\Deliveries.xlsm"
```

i am guessing i am missing a few big pieces but my googling isnt that smart in this area.

I am thinking that my batch file is what i then should make my windows task schedule run at a certain time in the future.

I have also tried this line of code that i found on google and edited it to fit my needs with no sucess.

```
   'Code should be placed in a .vbs file
      Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  objExcel.Application.Run "'C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Sales.xlsm'SalesModule.SalesTotal"
      objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False 
 objExcel.Application.Save 
      objExcel.Application.Quit
  Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Here i get error cant save workbook. Any Ideas? 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: So, why not make "HamtaData" onworkbookopen? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196215.aspx

Comment: @Andreas Maby it could work but i think, beacuse the file needs to be opened att several other times this could be a problem. The macro itself takes about 30 minutes to run so i wouldnt want to it to start every time i would like to check something in the file.

Comment: Nobody that has a clue?? I have tried multiple suggestions with code line in script,        objExcel.Application.Run "'full path to excel file'!module name.macro name" and nothing works. I get error cant run code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I will give you an answer that I kind of gave you in the comments.

I made a demo file to test it. http://hoppvader.nu/Run.xlsm

Basically, it's a run on workbook open. Ask user if he/she wants to run the macro.
If user is not present (inactive for 5 seconds) a sendkey will press enter, meaning run the macro.

This file then needs to be excecuted by windows task schedule and you need to make sure the "enable content warning" does not display by either disable the warning (bad idea) or create a signature for this macro (much better) https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Digitally-sign-a-macro-project-6e5de679-01d4-4387-85e0-92e3e9a49483 .

A "problem" with this is that the wait() will wait even if you click on "No", so this macro will cost you five seconds of your life each time you open it.

Code that runs in the file above:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    UserForm1.Show 0
    newHour = Hour(Now())
    newMinute = Minute(Now())
    newSecond = Second(Now()) + 5
    waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
    Application.Wait waitTime
    Application.SendKeys ("~")
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox "Run macro"
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    MsgBox "Don't run macro"
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Never used userforms before so thanks! Awesome stuff @Andreas Thnak u!

Comment: @DL1 No problem. One thing I have noticed is that the sendkeys() will fire even if you click no. Just to be safe, keep the messagebox with "don't run". This will give the sendkey a safe place to hit enter. Without this msgbox it will hit enter in the workbook. Maybe not a big deal, but better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Sorry @Andreas but i have another question if thats alright eventough the question is answered by u. When the script opens the workbook i cant have someone push ok in the msgbox that says run macro, if this is what starts the macro run process i mean. When i try to remove the msgbox for Macro Run the macro dont start. Any ideas would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: @DL1 The userform is needed. But the messageboxes was just "placeholders" to show what was what. So in button1_click() you should remove the "msg" line and add your code there. But you need to keep the unload line.

Comment: Thank u @Andreas I wrote a call HamtaData codeline and when i doubleclick the script to run it manualy it works but with task schedual its dead, Guess there something i am missing here.

Comment: That is odd. So the code runs automatically if you just open the workbook and wait the five seconds? But if task scheduler does it, it does not run? Need to think....

Comment: I figured out a smart other way to solve this problem if i can say it myself. My script only opens the workbook and in the workbook open sub i wrote a weekday and on time procedure. So my sub checks if the day is for example Tuesday and the time is let say 0700 then it runs HamtaData, Otherwise nothing